# It is possible use the same sql azure instance from two different cloud service of two different subscription?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-cloud-services

I have one Microsoft Azure subscription with one cloud service and one sql azure instance. Now I want create another cloud service with a different subscription (using a different microsoft account). With this second cloud service, can I use the same sql azure instance of the first subscription? (I need to share data between the two cloud service)

Or there may be performance issues?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Azure SQL DB instance can be accessed from different subscription as long as you have the connection string, username and password to the Azure SQL instance. As long as both the services are from the same region, there is no performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sure. From user perspective SQL Azure is mostly an ordinary SQL Server which you can access from anywhere in the world (given that the firewall rules allow that access) - from Azure services, from VMs in some other services hosted elsewhere, from your desktop, from servers in your company server room.

Network latency might kick in. Also more clients to the same instance mean more load. Also there's a limit on number of concurrent connections. Other than that - no problems.

Comment: What about other than sql servers ?

Comment: @Aatif I don't quite get the question.

Comment: Is the same thing (share data between the two cloud service) is possible for web/app server also ?

Comment: @Aatif If you store the data in some database or storage service which is accessible by multiple applications - sure.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure are a member in each Azure instance to be able to use the others SQL DB