# azure cross subscription authentication

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, database-connection

I have 2 azure subscriptions
I have a cloud service in 1 and a SQL db in the other one. I am getting authentication issues from my cloud service,Im assuming that its because the SQL db is in a different subscription?Im looking for documentation/confirmation that this is the case although this previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29406910/it-is-possible-use-the-same-sql-azure-instance-from-two-different-cloud-service) seems to indicate that it should be possible. The error message Im getting is along the lines of:

Login failed for user 'myuseraccount'.b1234f57e567.tr6.northeurope1-a.worker.database.windows.net,111105CCA891A-CF11-4101-BF19-CDEF1B4B9365

Comment: Seems it was because the was a space in the db name!!!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out, trying to figure out if I can use a imported AD in one subscription to authenticate SQL in another. Not sure if its possible or not.